# ASP.NET URL rewriting like Wikipedia

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, url-routing, wikipedia

I have searched the Internet, and it looked like there are three options

1. The old, hard way : create some URL handler extension for IIS (I am not sure if the terminologies are correct).
2. .NET 3.5 way: create some sort of URL handler class with complicated Web.config modification.
3. The new, easy .NET 4.0 way: Call MapPageRoute in Global.asax.cs.

I tried 2 first, but failed to make it work. Then I tried 3, but also failed. After some efforts, I found that my IIS was set to use .net 2.0 app pool by default. Now I succeeded 3.

But the problem is it does not work when the URL contains something like **/,\, %, &**.... When defining a new page in Wikipedia even a/b works. I want exactly that. How can I make URL's like

```
http://[my server name]/[whatever words except some special names like 'admin']
```

work like Wikipedia? Should I use the option 1? Or can I still use option 3 with some special settings? (Of course, I want the easiest way... :))

Comment: I do so when there is a suitable answer.

Comment: Sounds like an URL encoding problem somewhere. You have to make sure that the URL's that your application generates (e.g. for links) are properly URL encoded and if your code rewrites to an aspx page and uses the slug in a query parameter is should also properly URL encoded the text.